# Makefile - Providing Optional Arguments

Tags: command-line, make

I'm very new to scripting and makefiles, and am curious about the passing of command line arguments. So, let's say I have a makefile which compiles and runs something in C, for example

```
CompileAndRun: CompileFile RunFile
    
CompileFile:
    (Compiling code)

RunFile:
    ./Program
```

I would call this with

```
make CompileAndRun
```

What I want to have happen is, if I type

```
make CompileAndRun Argument
```

Then it would compile, and then do

```
./Program Argument
```

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic way to do this is to pass a *variable* which you can then refer to in the Makefile, for example:

```
CompileAndRun: CompileFile RunFile
    
CompileFile:
    (Compiling code)

RunFile:
    ./Program $(ARGUMENTS)
```

You can now `make RunFile` to run it without any arguments or `make ARGUMENTS="foo bar" RunFile` to run it with two arguments `foo` and `bar`. Beware that you can't pass arguments containing whitespace characters this way.